Azure MS SQL Always On Availibity Group Setup Issue
I have 2 VMs on azure where MS SQL server is configured with always on high availability, one VM is acting as primary and other one is secondary. On top of that, there is domain controller VM which is managing both VMs. For DNS we have Cloudflare and IPs of both VMs are added as A record.
But the problem is sometimes my app creates connection with secondary (read only) when both IPs added in DNS, so its look like connection is fluctuating as SQL listener name (server name) is resolvable from both IPs. Is there any way to bind the app with primary only and request should not go to secondary.
I am using below service connection string in my application.
Server=server-ip or listner url;
Initial Catalog=Database name;
Persist Security Info=False;
User ID=username;
Password=password;
MultipleActiveResultSets=False;
Encrypt=True;
TrustServerCertificate=True 


@BrendanMcCaffrey Yes, multiple IPs (Primary & Secondary) are assigned to the listener in order to resolve it from both IPs.
`Listener DNS Name: xyzlistener
Port: 1433
Network Mode: Static IP
Subnet               IP
10.0.1.0/24         10.0.1.1
10.0.2.0/24         10.0.2.1`
Do we need to make any change here?


I have 2 VMs on azure where MS SQL server is configured with always on high availability, one VM is acting as primary and other one is secondary.


But the problem is sometimes my app creates connection with secondary (read only) when both IPs added in DNS, so its look like connection is fluctuating as SQL listener name (server name) is resolvable from both IPs.

You'll need to follow the Microsoft documentation on Availability Group setup in Azure. You're choices are using a DNN, Load Balancer, or each replica in its won subnet (which is how AWS runs).
